# Python 2 compiler.ast replacements for Python 3, functions Discard and Const

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to convert an older library that maps dependencies called snakefood over to Python 3.  I have 2 parts I can't figure out what to substitute as I can't find documentation on what either function does - `from compiler.ast import Discard, Const`  I can't seem to find an equivalent in Python 3 in the  `ast` library.  Here are the function calls from Python 2, see both here being used in `isinstance()` calls:

```
    def default(self, node):
        pragma = None
        if self.recent:
            if isinstance(node, Discard):
                children = node.getChildren()
                if len(children) == 1 and isinstance(children[0], Const):
                    const_node = children[0]
                    pragma = const_node.value

        self.accept_imports(pragma)
```

Apologies for not understanding this stuff, I just learned about AST calls trying to use this library.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Discard` (took me a while to figure out what it does) is now `Expr` (though this includes more things than previously)

I got this hint from the source of compiler/codegen.py:

```
    def visitDiscard(self, node):
        # XXX Discard means it's an expression.  Perhaps this is a bad
        # name.
```

`Const` has been replaced with several different types which represent various constants, notably `Num`, `Str`, `JoinedStr`, and a few others.  The documentation for all the ast types [can be found here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

Comment: So a `Discard` node that contains only a `Const` child would be something like a docstring.

Comment: @jasonharper I also see it for numbers: `>>> compiler.parse('2') Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Const(2))]))`